# How to make a Service run at a specific time in Android?

Tags: android, service

So I have this code in order to start a service at 7:32 AM every day:

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);


Intent start = new Intent(getActivity(), Services.class);
PendingIntent PI = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, start, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, PI);
getActivity().startService(start);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't start the service at the specified time. Can someone help me?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Doesn't start any service, doesn't start the right service, doesn't start at the right time, etc?

Comment: @GabeSechan okay, see the edited post:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off your repeat won't work because you're setting the interval to 10 seconds.  To make it happen daily, you want 1000*60*60*24.]

Secondly, the add to your calendar is off.  You want `cur_cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)`.  This will move it to tomorrow.  What you're doing is basically multiplying it by 2.

Comment: It worked, but it doesn't run the service when I closed the app